# How to access the variable declared in the xaml designer page?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

In my page.xaml has the declaration as follows

```xml
<Label Text="Location" Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}" />
<ContentView Style="{StaticResource fieldView}">
    <Label Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource fieldStyle}" />
</ContentView>
```

I am trying to access the variable Location.Text in xaml.cs page. However, I couldn't access the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a name to an element to access it from the code behind:

in the XAML:

```
<Label x:Name="txtLoc" Text="Location" Style="{StaticResource labelStyle}" />
```

in the code behind:

```
var loc = txtLoc.Text;
```